# GlassFish 4 cannot Deploy

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I use GlassFish4 in Eclipse for Java Dynamic Web Development. GlassFish cannot deploy my project anymore. I have already tried several methods on stackoverflow and on the internet in general to fix it.

I can't even access the admin console via localhost:4848. I see the surface of the glassfish console but it says "Status: The Admin Console Application is not yet installed."

This is my error:

```
 [2018-05-05T20:28:14.580+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00093] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=104 _ThreadName=Thread-23] [timeMillis: 1525544894580] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Problem while attempting to install admin console!
org.jvnet.hk2.config.TransactionFailure: A ApplicationRef with the same key "__admingui" already exists in Server server
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigSupport._apply(ConfigSupport.java:209)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigSupport.apply(ConfigSupport.java:139)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.install(InstallerThread.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread.run(InstallerThread.java:99)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ApplicationRef with the same key "__admingui" already exists in Server server
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.WriteableView$ProtectedList.add(WriteableView.java:648)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter.InstallerThread$1.run(InstallerThread.java:161)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.config.ConfigSupport._apply(ConfigSupport.java:180)
    ... 3 more
]]
```

I appreciate every kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are working with a local instance of the glassfish application server. You could check if you acomplished the requirements listed in the [GF 4.1 Release Notes](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/documentation4) before you did the installation.

Another action you can take is to verify the integrity of your domain.xml configuration file using the command `asadmin verify-domain-xml` from *your installation-directory/bin* folder

You say you cannot access the admin console, but is your server even running? (http://localhost:8080/).

You can also take a look at the server.log for some more hints on what is going on, which you can find in *installation-directory/domains/domain-name/logs*, or try to do [a manual deployment via asadmin](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/4.0/quick-start-guide.pdf) and see what happens.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. The glassfish server runs (again). I don't know what I've did, but it runs and that's okay. I can't access the admin console though. But I already could. I tried using your command "asadmin verify-domain-xml" but it only gives me this reply "Comand asadmin not found. Check the entry of command name. This command may be provided by a package that is not installed. Command asadmin failed."

Comment: `asadmin` is a tool that comes with GlassFish. What Mario is suggesting is that you go to your *installation-directory/bin*  folder and run the tool which, in Mac/Linux operating systems, would mean running `./asadmin verify-domain-xml`. This tells the terminal that you want it to look in the current directory for `asadmin`. Alternatively, you could give the absolute path to the file which would do the same thing, e.g. `/home/user_name/glassfish4/bin/asadmin verify-domain-xml`.